# Get admin password of a ESXI host from managing Vcenter via power CLI or other ways

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, vcenter

If a ESXI host is managed my a Vcenter . Then is there any way I can know the ESXI host root/admin password from the vCenter ? Either via vcenter GUI or some command line tool like power CLI.

Answer (score 1):

On various forums I asked about that , and ultimate conclusion is that admin password is not available for esxi host via vcenter.

This is private information and there is no API call via which vcenter exposes this information  to users of vCenter  client.